# Find $f(x)$, $\begin{vmatrix} \alpha & x&x&x\\ x& \beta &x &x \\ x& x & \gamma &x \\ x& x& x &\delta \end{vmatrix} = f(x)-xf'(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 \alpha & x&x&x\\
 x& \beta &x  &x  \\
 x& x & \gamma &x  \\
 x&  x& x &\delta 
\end{vmatrix} = f(x)-xf'(x)$$
Here's how I approached it$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 \alpha & x&x&x\\
 x& \beta &x  &x  \\
 x& x & \gamma &x  \\
 x&  x& x &\delta 
\end{vmatrix} = g(x)$$
$$ f(x)=y$$

$$g(x)=y-x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{y}{x} = -\frac{g(x)}{x}$$ $$I.F = \frac{1}{x} $$
$$\frac{y}{x}=\int -\frac{g(x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$y =-x\int \begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\alpha}{x} &1  &1  &1  \\
1 &\frac{\beta}{x}  &1  &1  \\ 
 x& x & \gamma &x  \\
 x&x  &x  & \delta
\end{vmatrix} dx$$
This is where I get stuck. Computing this determinant is annoying in itself but the constant of integration is also a pain. We cannot obtain constant of integration by inputting $x=0$ in original equation and thus need to use another value of x and need to compute both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ for finding the constant.
Is there an easier way to solve this (by hand)?

Comment: @MartinR That's exactly what I needed, thanks.